Can you suggest me a Greek font that has the same (or very similar) text glyphs with the Latin characters of Concrete font?
Please see the next MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
    
    Αυτό το κείμενο είναι γραμμένο στα Ελληνικά αλλά η γραμματοσειρά που χρησιμοποιείται για τα Ελληνικά από το σύστημα είναι πολύ διαφορετική από τη γραμματοσειρά που χρησιμοποιείται για τους Λατινικούς χαρακτήρες
    
    \textlatin{This text is written with the Concrete font but the characters used for Latin text are very different than the characters used for Greek text, it seems like is onother font. }
    
\end{document}

As you can see Greek characters differ a lot from Latin characters of Concrete font.
Can you suggest me a font package (LGR) or an OTF for unicode machines that supports Greek characters that are very similar with the Latin characters of Concrete font?

Can you switch to an unicode engine like lualatex? With CMU Concrete: https://i.sstatic.net/CvBjRLrk.png

Yes I can do this easily.

There exists another variation, but it contains only the normal and italic typefaces. And the kerning isn't very satisfactory in my opinion. https://github.com/jarnosz/Concrete-LGC

Thanks for the information. I will try it and I will decide which one give me best results.

With an unicode engine like lualatex, you could use the CMU Concrete font:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}


\begin{document}
    
    Αυτό το κείμενο είναι γραμμένο στα Ελληνικά αλλά η γραμματοσειρά που χρησιμοποιείται για τα Ελληνικά από το σύστημα είναι πολύ διαφορετική από τη γραμματοσειρά που χρησιμοποιείται για τους Λατινικούς χαρακτήρες
    
    \textlatin{This text is written with the Concrete font but the characters used for Latin text are very different than the characters used fpr Greek text, it seems like is onother font. }
    
\end{document}



@user691586 Fixed! Thanks a lot!
